# Integral of $\int_{1}^{2}(\sqrt{x^{2}+1}\cdot x) dx$

Tags: integration

I am trying to evaluate this integral and faced with the following problem:
$$\int_{1}^{2}(\sqrt{x^{2}+1}\cdot x) dx$$
what I tried to do is:
set $\sqrt{x^2+1}=t$ tried to make derivative but not success.
any suggestions?
thanks!

Comment: take x = tan(t)

Comment: No substitution:

$$\int \sqrt {x^2+1}x\,\mathrm dx=\dfrac 12\int 2x(x^2+1)^{1/2}\mathrm dx\overset{f(x)=x^2+1}{=}\dfrac 12 \int f'(x)(f(x))^{1/2}\mathrm dx=\\ =\dfrac {1}{2} \int \left(\dfrac 23(f(x))^{3/2}\right)'\mathrm dx=\dfrac{(f(x))^{3/2}}{3}=\dfrac{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}{3}.$$

Now compute the definite integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting
$$
t=x^2+1,
$$
we get
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_1^2 x\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx&=&\frac12\int_2^5\sqrt{t}\,dt=\frac13\left[t^{3/2}\right]_2^5=\frac{5\sqrt{5}-2\sqrt{2}}{3}.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The square root is going to give you problems. Try $t = x^2 + 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Try making the substitution $t = 1+x^2$ which has $dt = 2x~dx$. Often times it's easier to use just the stuff under the radical when doing substitutions so you don't have to deal as much with the fact that the derivative of $\sqrt x$ is $\frac{-1}{\sqrt x}$.